# About PHP null coalescing operator

Tags: php

I thought following code failed with **Attempt to read property "hoge" on null**.

```
$a = null;
$result = $a->hoge->hoge ?? 'default';
print_r($result);
```

But it works fine.
Why does this code work fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of $result will be 'default' because you have used ?? operator

In $result = $a->hoge->hoge ?? 'default', it will first check if $a exist and if it exist then it will check if it has hoge property or not and if it has that property then it will check if that hoge property has hoge or not and if it has then it will assign the value of it to $result variable but in your code $a doesn't have any property then it will assign the second value 'default' to $result

You can run this code too where $a isn't even defined and I'm still using it to assign it's value to $result, but though $a doesn't even exist so the second value will be assigned

```
$result = $a->hoge->hoge ?? 'default';
print_r($result);
```

In short, it will check if first value exist or not, if it exist then it will assign it's value otherwise it will assign second value given to ?? operator

Comment: i think isset() is used internally. So above code is not failed.